# Mobile responsive css not overlapping desktop css

Tags: html, css

I have the below css custom class

> .textblock

being called in the html and I have made custom sizes for mobile however it's still taking the desktop version. the weird thing is that td is working fine but text-block isn't.

F.Y.I text-block is div class being called inside my table structure .

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 700px) {
    td {
        display:inline-block;
        padding:5px;
        width:100%;
    }
    p{
    font-size:2vw;
    }
    .text-block{
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #101010;
    width: 40%;
    top: 108px;
    }
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  
}

.text-block {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 77px;
    left: 40px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #101010;
    padding-left: 40px;
    width: 40%;

}
}
```

[image]

Comment: move the `media` section **after** the regular css. if it spirit stylesheet load the media sheet after the normal sheet

Comment: happy to help :)